# Greek letters - JSON

Tags: json, character

I have a JSON file with Greek names and letters ie.

```
{
 "playerId":1,
 "name":"Τ. Παπαγιάννης",
 "position":"Τερματοφύλακας",
 "age":"21",
 "number":"15",
 "photo":"/papagiannis.jpg",
 "details":"Ακαδημίες ΑΕΛ"
}
```

I display this file on google chrome browser(through a local server called wamp) and it is a mess.
[image: JSON picture]

Is there any way to change that?

Thank you.

Theo.

**FIXED**

I used notepad++ then went to Encoding->Encode to UTF-8. That simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the encoding to UTF-8

Comment: thank you for the reply. how should I do that exactly?

Comment: U are using WAMP, so you are serving over http I suppose. Then you can set the appropriate response header to UTF-8